# Finding Clique using graph and vertices

Tags: python

PYTHON ONLY!!

I have a graph

```
graph = [[0,1,1,1,0],
             [1,0,0,0,0],
             [0,1,0,1,1],
             [1,0,1,0,1],
             [0,0,1,1,0]]
```

The function clique(graph, vertices) should take an adjacency matrix
representation of a graph, a list of one or more vertices, and return a boolean True if the vertices create a clique
(every person is friends with every other person), otherwise return False.

```
 `def clique(graph, vertices)`
```

I want to find out whether does a clique exists in the graph above

If yes the output should be True, otherwise False

eg. 'clique', (graph,[2,3,4]), True)]

Explanation needed thanks!

Comment: `explanation needed thanks`, indeed

Comment: Please can you better explain what the problem is, and what you want help with?

Comment: Ahhh sure. I want to find the clique of the graph using def clique(graph, vertices). true is it is and false if it isnt.

Comment: `I want to find the clique of the graph` this makes absolutely no sense to someone without any context of the problem

Comment: The function clique(graph, vertices) should take an adjacency matrix
representation of a graph, a list of one or more vertices, and return a boolean True if the vertices create a clique
(every person is friends with every other person), otherwise return False.

Comment: i think i should've put it as whether the clique exists in the graph sorry. my apologies .

Comment: Okay, makes more sense now. Please update your question accordingly, and also add some examples where the output should be True, and some with False, and the reasoning please. Otherwise it'll be prone to confusion

Comment: Please add also the examples, as mentioned. And what module have you thought to use? NetworkX for instance? Or just python? Please clarify

Comment: Ok with the edit the question suddenly becam very different and makes a lot more sense. Checking whether a subgraph is a clique is easy, finding cliques in a graph, not so much.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience i guess i didn't understand the question well myself.

Answer (score 0):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem

Here you go, depending on what problem you ACTUALLY want to solve, here you have a starting point for finding an algorithm.

Is a graph a clique: Just check that all nodes are adjacent to each other.

Does it contain a clique? Always true if the graph is non-empty because a single vertex is already a clique of size one.

Does it contain a clique of size k? brute force it

Find a single maximal clique? Greedy algorithm possible as described in the link.

Find all maximal cliques? see wikipedia page for references (this is hard)